# How to address : The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout error: on IIS 7.5

Tags: php, iis

**My PHP script executes some program on my server IIS 7.5

Takes time about 10 mins to execute but above error in browser.

How to resolve this.**

**Error:**

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\php\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout  

Module  FastCgiModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler FastCGI
Error Code  0x80070102
```

**php.ini settings:**

```
fastcgi.impersonate = 1
fastcgi.logging = 0
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
cgi.force_redirect = 0  

max_execution_time = 0
upload_max_filesize = 20M
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 30M
```

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\ **applicationHost.config** file settings for fast-cgi

```
<fastCgi>
<application  
fullPath="C:\php\php-cgi.exe" activityTimeout = "3600" requestTimeout = "300" />
</fastCgi>
```

Comment: so how did you fix this? did you increase both (activityTimeout and requestTimeout) or just one of those?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is sort of a quick explanation of what is going on. When you are using a CGI/FCGI configuration for PHP. The webserver (in this case IIS), routes requests that require php processing to the PHP process (which runs separately from the web server).

Generally, to prevent connections from getting stuck open and waiting (if php process happens to crash) the web server will only wait a set amount of time for the PHP process to return a result (usually 30-60 seconds).

In your configuration you have this:

```
requestTimeout = "300"
```

300 seconds = 5 minutes. IIS will cancel the request since your request takes 10 minutes to complete. Simple fix, increase the timeout to something 600 or greater.

Now, running a script for 10 minutes with an http request is not a good design pattern. Generally, http works best with short lived requests. The reason is that timeouts can exist in any part of the process (server, proxy, or client) and the script could be accidentally interrupted.

So, when you have a web application that has a long running job like this, the best way to run it is via console or job queue.

Comment: I changed requestTimeout = "1000" and script took 5.5 mins to run. but same error. I had restarted server before run. It seems if my users want larger file to be processed by my app, it would be better if I use  console or job que. But I don't know how.

Comment: Do you have any logging for errors? You didn't mention file uploads before, there could be something else at work as well.

Comment: It takes text files to process. I call a perl script via php and run the perl to give out files to user. The files are uploaded fine (I get those in my root folder) this means no error in file size or type.

Comment: You kinda of already have a start do go down the job queue route. With this error, do you have display_errors enabled in php.ini? If the error is not written to a log, you should be able to get it on screen.

Answer (score 5):

There is one more setting I found from this [source](https://serverfault.com/questions/541413/how-to-fix-the-fastcgi-process-exceeded-configured-activity-timeout-on-windows) that helped me with the same problem I was having.
Copied and pasted:

Open Server Manager

At Server Level (not default Web site)

- Double click FastCGI Settings
- open PHP.EXE listed there
- Monitor changes to file php.ini
- activity timeout default is 60s - change to 600s or whatever

Answer (score 1):

This can be solve by adjusting fast-cgi configuration.
Goto **"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\"** and edit **"fcgiext.ini"** file

```
[PHP]
ExePath=C:\xampp\php\php-cgi.exe
MonitorChangesTo=C:\xampp\php\php.ini
ActivityTimeout=3600
IdleTimeout=3600
RequestTimeout=3600
```

Make sure to place ActivityTimeout,IdleTimeout & RequestTimeout inside [PHP] section as shown above.

Comment: I could not find that file at that location. I was able to make those same config changes through IIS->FastCGI Settings->Edit->Process Model